# why can't Panel_register SetActivity to (false) after Firebase CreateUser?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine

why can't Panel_register SetActivity to (false) after Firebase CreateUser?

after i create successfully User in Firebase i want disabel the visibility of Panel_Register

or

opening a new scene is only possible if you are logged in

```
public Text email;
public Text password;

public GameObject Panel_Register;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

/** Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
**/

public void Register()
{
    FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email.text, password.text).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        // Firebase user has been created.
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
            newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);

        //login panel ausblenden
        Panel_Register.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    });

}
```